# data manipulation in Excel: search row backwards and extract only non-repeated data

Tags: excel

I have a dataset of herbicide applications and the dates they were applied. 
For example, the raw dataset looks like this, where 'h1' is herbicide 1, and 'd1' is the application date for herbicide 1, etc (herbicides denoted by capital letters):

```
h1  d1          h2  d2          h3  d3          h4  d4          h5  d5
A   30/09/15    B   20/10/15    C   20/10/15    D   20/10/15    E   15/03/16
W   15/09/15    X   15/09/15    NA  15/09/15    Z   04/04/16    A   30/07/16
A   30/09/15    NA  NA          C   13/11/15    D   15/03/16    P   18/04/16
A   30/09/15    B   20/10/15    C   20/10/15    P   20/10/15    Q   20/10/15
```

I have concatenated herbicides that were applied on the same dates, so now the dataset looks like this:

```
h1  d1          h2  d2          [h1,h2] h3  d3          [h2,h3] [h1,h2,h3]  h4  d4          [h3,h4] [h2,h3,h4]  [h1,h2,h3,h4]   h5  d5          [h4,h5] [h3,h4,h5]  [h2,h3,h4,h5]   [h1,h2,h3,h4,h5]
A   30/09/15    B   20/10/15    FALSE   C   20/10/15    B + C   FALSE       D   20/10/15    C + D   B + C + D   FALSE           E   15/03/16    FALSE   FALSE       FALSE           FALSE
W   15/09/15    X   15/09/15    W + X   NA  15/09/15    X + NA  W + X + NA  Z   04/04/16    FALSE   FALSE       FALSE           A   30/07/16    FALSE   FALSE       FALSE           FALSE
A   30/09/15    NA  NA          FALSE   C   13/11/15    FALSE   FALSE       D   15/03/16    FALSE   FALSE       FALSE           P   18/04/16    FALSE   FALSE       FALSE           FALSE
A   30/09/15    B   20/10/15    FALSE   C   20/10/15    B + C   FALSE       P   20/10/15    C + P   B + C + P   FALSE           Q   20/10/15    P + Q   C + P + Q   B + C + P + Q   FALSE
```

The next step is where I am stuck.
I would like to create the final dataset looking like this, where 'ap1' is the first application of herbicide(s), and 'ap.date1' is the date that the first herbicide(s) was/were applied:

```
ap1     ap.date1    ap2             ap.date2    ap3   ap.date3   ap4     ap.date4
A       30/09/15    B + C + D       20/10/15    E     15/03/16  
W + X   15/09/15    Z               04/04/16    A     30/07/16
A       30/09/15    C               13/11/15    D     15/03/16   P       18/04/16
A       30/09/15    B + C + P + Q   20/10/15
```

I have replaced all FALSE with NA, and I have replaced any concatenated entry containing '+ NA', for example:

```
W + X + NA
```

with simply

```
NA
```

I do not wish to keep anything that is NA.

I have tried IF formulae without joy.

I've tried formulae along the lines of

```
=MAX(COLUMN($W2:$AR2))-MAX(IF($W2:$AR2<>"NA",COLUMN($W2:$AR2)))
```

to identify the position of the last cell containing text, but it's not very helpful.

I have Googled extensively but haven't managed to solve the issue.

The herbicides go up to h7 and there are thousands of rows.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you would greatly benefit from using VBA

Comment: This is what I was worried someone would say. I don't know VBA. Are you able to point me to a useful tutorial? I suppose the other alternative is to do it in R. Again, no idea (yet!) how to do that either.

Comment: There are plenty of tuturials on VBA around. Try searching for Loop's, using Step -1, and IF statements can also be used in VBA. In your case: IF NOT cell.value = "False" then dostuff

Comment: Thank you Luuklag

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! with help from a friend using lookup tables and concatenateIf.